# What does @a, @c in documentation strings mean?

Tags: eclipse, tizen

Eclipse's built-in help shows `@a` and `@c` for some methods, here is an example:

> @remarks This creates a window like `elm_win_add()`, but also puts in a
>   standard background using `elm_bg_add()` as well as setting the window
>   title to **@a title**. The window type created is of type **@c ELM_WIN_BASIC**
>   with **@c NULL** as the parent widget.

What does `@a` and `@c` mean?

Answer (score 3):

Looks like JavaDoc-style markup, which is also supported by Doxygen.

From [the doxygen documentation](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/commands.html#cmd_intro):

> All commands in the documentation start with a backslash (`\`) or an at-sign (`@`).
> ...
>
> **`\a <word>`**
> Displays the argument  in italics. Use this command to emphasize words. Use this command to refer to member arguments in the running text.
>
> **`\c <word>`**
> Displays the argument  using a typewriter font. Use this to refer to a word of code. Equivalent to <tt>word</tt>.

Comment: don't think it is same as you explained because it also contains @remarks with @a and @c

Comment: I'm not sure why you think that would matter(?). The doxygen documentation even says _"Starts a paragraph where one or more remarks may be entered. ... All visual enhancement commands may be used inside the paragraph."_.

Comment: I misunderstood it, after more reading i found this could be a similar documentation as you explained above, thanks for clearing my doubt.